# Spark - How to count amount of all single products stored in array under certain column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm kinda new to spark and already got one task. I have a DF with column "cart" which is an StructType holding strings. My goal is to separate all of these products and count the amount of each.

I have already done that using python approach and it works. I'm curious if my approach is correct or it should've been done via raw spark? I'm adding screenshoot of my work from databricks platform.

Important:
I do not want the ready solution - Just hints which methods of pyspark i should use :)

[SPARK EXCERSISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yZKD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `count` command.

`df.groupBy("Column").count().show()`